# How to handle changing input element numbers and multiple action in Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Hi Respected group members. I have query related to RL. Please help me in pointing me to the right direction. I am fairly new to RL and hence my question may sound silly so please bear with me. 
Suppose e.g. task is to arrange n elements on a canvas. Action that can be applied on each element is two dimensional [move up/down, move left/right]. Agent has time limit to finish the task and once time is up it will be given reward if arrangement is right. Next task again will be same but number of elements and canvas dimensions can change. How to handle this scenario using RL as number of actions will change as number of elements will change from one task to another

Comment: How many elements are you thinking of having. I.e. what's the maximum of n? Why not have the action space with size 4 * max(n). For small n most of the actions in training won't do anything. Just to confirm are you using a neural network?

Comment: Also can any of the elements go to any goal position or does each element have it's own unique goal position?

Comment: Hi Marcus, yes i can limit the number of elements as max(n) lets say 10. I am planning to use a neural network yes. Any element can go to any goal position but its position depends upon the position of other element e.g. any element should not overlap with other element. How will my neural network look like it should have 4*max(n) as output layer? How should i map an action to a particular element? I mean how do i map these actions to which element i should apply this action set to ?

Answer (score 0):

One method you could consider depending on the detail of your game. If each element has the same goal and same actions you could train an agent that solves for a single element getting to the goal. Once trained you can add more elements and pass each element through the network to get an action for each element. 
We have implemented something very similar. The beauty of it is that you only have to train with one element making it much quicker. Also once trained you can have any number of elements and the agent will be able to solve it as easily as if there was one element. All depends on the detail of your game and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, in my game presence of one element affect other e.g. consider the scenario where my agent is trying to arrange indoor furniture for hall, i a have set of furnitures lets say table, chair , tv , tv stand etc. now there are multiple plausible arrangements but every arrangement should be logical e.g. table should be close to chair , tv should be on top of tv stand etc. Once i train an agent for this task how do i make sure that it can ge generalised to other rooms which may have different dimensions and  different number of furnitures.